# After update gradle ver apk size twice bigger, why?

Tags: android, gradle

I had gradle

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.3'
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.4.1-all.zip
```

and my apk 160Mb

[image]

then I update it to

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.3'
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.6.4-all.zip
```

and my apk size is 270Mb

[image]

How is it possible? But acctually if I build `.aab` it is still has 160Mb, so size increasing if I build `.apk`

Comment: Were you able to find more info about this? We're noticing the same thing and it appears the native libs used to be compressed in the apk/zip file and no longer are. If you're on a Mac/Linux box, run `unzip -vl apkname.apk` and look at the second column to see if your .so files are deflated before and only stored after.

Answer (score 15):

This is caused by a change in the Gradle plugin which used to zip deflate the native libraries, but now just stores them. [According to Google](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin#extractNativeLibs) this ends up being a benefit for end users:

> - Smaller app install size because the platform can access the native
>     libraries directly from the installed APK, without creating a copy of
>     the libraries.
> - Smaller download size because Play Store compression is
>     typically better when you include uncompressed native libraries in
>     your APK or Android App Bundle.

According to that same link, you can revert this change by setting `extractNativeLibs` to `true`

Comment: Very useful info...thanks a lot. Cheers :)

Answer (score 4):

add this tag on you **AndroidManifest.xml** file

```
android:extractNativeLibs="true"
```

example:

```
<application
    android:extractNativeLibs="true"
    ... >
</application>
```

Comment: after a 5 to 8 hours i understands why apk size is increased , i update gradle v7.0.2 and my apk size is increased 100%. OMG ... but you save me really dear thank u

Comment: welcome man that was also my problem

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, but the provided solution was not working. For those having multidex enabled on your APK your must add the following instead:

```
android {
packagingOptions {
    dex {
        useLegacyPackaging true
    }
}
```

}

on your module build.gradle

Source : https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin#dex_files_uncompressed_in_apks_when_minsdk_28_or_higher

Answer (score 1):

i had the same problem the only thing that help me little is to add `abiFilter` in `build.gradle` inside `defaultConfig`

```
ndk{
    abiFilters "mips","mips64","armeabi","armeabi-v7a","arm64-v8a"
}
```